# Multivariable Calculus Vectors

Tags: calculus, vectors

Find an equation for the plane that is perpendicular to the line $l(t)=(5,0,2)t+(3,-1,1)$ and passes through $(5,-1,0)$

Answer (score 1):

First find two linear independent vectors perpendicular to vector $(5,0,2)$, for example $(0,1,0)$ and $(-2,0,5)$. Next you can write quation of the plane which you find $\{(0,1,0)t+(-2,0,5)s+(5,-1,0) : s,t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ (if you put $s=t=0$ you see that plane passes through point $(5,-1,0)$).

Comment: Very clear.  Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the equation of the line, you can determine the normal vector of the plane; it's (5,0,2).  Do you see why?

Now you have a normal vector and a point for a plane.  Let's call the normal vector $\hat{n}$, and the point $p_0$.  We know that any vector in the plane is perpendicular to its normal vector.  This can be written as follows:
$ \hat{n} \cdot (p-p_0) = 0 $.  And this is the equation of the plane.

The point $p$ can be rewritten componentwise as $p=(x,y,z)$.  Then our equation becomes $(5,0,2) \cdot ( (x,y,z) - (5,-1,0) ) = 0$.  This can be expanded out further if desired.

Comment: thank you so much. thanks to you i realized how much i was overthinking this problem

Comment: Sweet!  Glad I could help.

Comment: can i ask you another problem then too? if you don't mind?

Comment: Feel free.  It may be better to post it as a new question to the forum though.  Also, it'd be sweet if you could mark my explanation as the answer, if you feel like it did answer your question.

Comment: Because I can't post until another 20 minutes and I'm in a hurry I'll out it here if you don't mind:                           Find an equation for the plane that passes through (3,2,-1) and (1,-1,2) and is parallel to the line v=(1,-1,0)+t(3,2,-2)

Comment: Ask away.  I'll try my best.

Comment: Well you have two points in the plane, so you have one vector that lies in the plane.  You also have a line that's parallel to the plane, so you know another vector that lies in the plane.  You have two vectors in the plane.  You can then proceed according to agha's answer.

Comment: alright thank you so much